# searchWords.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am using react-highlight-words package to highlight the text entered in the textbox
- I referred react-highlight-words documenation in that they are passing searchWords as an array. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highlight-words
- but the problem is when I pass it an array `let searchBarText = [];` I am facing an error searchWords.filter is not a function.
- Can you tell me how to fix it, so that in future I will fix it myself.
- Providing my sandbox and code snippet below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/00nm6k8orp

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      // testHighlight: {}
      testHighlight: []
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value); // your search bar text
    let object = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    console.log(object.textContent); // your div text

    // now that you have the two strings you can do your search in your favorite way, for example:
    let searchBarText = [];
    searchBarText = e.target.value;
    console.log("searchBarText --->", searchBarText);

    let divText = object.textContent;
    console.log("divText --->", divText);

    if (divText.includes(searchBarText)) {
      console.log("the div text contains your search text");
    } else {
      console.log("the div text doesn't contain search text");
    }

    // this.setState({ testHighlight: response.data });

    this.setState({ testHighlight: searchBarText });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="input"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder="Search..."
          // highlightText={this.handleChange}
          testHighlight={this.state.testHighlight}
        />

        <HighlighterImplementation testHighlight={this.state.testHighlight} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `SearchBar.js` file you are updating the `testHighlight` to a string:

```
this.setState({ testHighlight: searchBarText });
```

Didn't you mean to do:

```
 this.setState({ testHighlight: [searchBarText] });
```

Or if you want to add it to the existing array:

```
this.setState({ testHighlight: [...this.state.testHighlight, searchBarText] });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state 'testHighlight' is being saved as a string and 'HighlighterImplementation' component needs the 'testHighlight' as an array.

So, while setting the state as a prop, you should change that state in an array. split() method can change the string to an array of strings.

You have added searchBarText initial state but in the on change event, it is updated as the string;

```
this.setState({ testHighlight: searchBarText });
```

so, if you modify the above line to:

```
<HighlighterImplementation testHighlight={this.state.testHighlight.split('')} />
```

and while initializing state it should be the string will do the trick

Comment: can you explain in detail...its hard to understand :(

Comment: @nossr, updated the answer please have a look, if you have still any questions please let me know

Comment: @nossr also the package you are using needs searchBarText props as an array of words to match and highlight the text, that is the reason we are using split('') in order to convert string into array of words.

Comment: I have added some changes in the sandbox, in case you need reference https://codesandbox.io/s/yp6kx7njxv

Comment: so split converts strings into array? and why your using or operation and checking empty in  ` testHighlight={this.state.testHighlight.split('') || ''} `

Comment: oh!! my bad, that should be like following:
testHighlight={this.state.testHighlight.split('')}, updated (like)

Comment: @nossr rather to split with nothing its better to do like: testHighlight={[this.state.testHighlight]}

Comment: but will the split also will work...can you give comments in sandbox ...that would be great

Comment: hey it should be array right, since they are passing searchWords as an array.   testHighlight: "" //changed initial state to string

Comment: testHighlight={this.state.testHighlight.split('') we are converting it into array over here when we are passing it into HighlighterImplementation component

Comment: Hope this may help, please accept the answer if it is helpful.